# summing up bigint values in a column

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table in mysql (v 5.6.23) that is described as follows:

```
mysql> describe as_dcm_testing;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| LCID         | varchar(32) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| LASTACTIVITY | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| USAGE        | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SERVICELEVEL | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to sum up all of the values in the USAGE column so I tried using the sum function. The issue is I seem to be getting an error . Is this error because usage is BIGINT instead of INT? How do I sum up the values in a column with bigint values?

```
mysql> select SUM(USAGE) as usage from as_dcm_testing;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USAGE) as usage from as_dcm_testing' at line 1
mysql>
```

Thanks in advance

A

Comment: USAGE is a reserved keyword, use `USAGE` instead. (add the ` around it signs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`USAGE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_usage) is a reserved word in MySQL. You have to enclose it in backticks:

```
select SUM(`USAGE`) as `usage` from as_dcm_testing;
```